# How to draw a line in a right angle from another line in a SVG Path

Tags: svg

I am drawing an arch and then want to draw a line from the end of the arch with a given length in an right angle.

I know about the L and the V command, but for the L command I need a specific point which I dont have and the V command is not in a right angle to the given point.

Is there any other command that could help me or should I just try to calculate the endpoint and then use L command?

If so how would you try to calculate it?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

My code looks like this:

```
$arcpath = "<path d=\"M $circstartx $circstarty L $startx $starty A $radius $radius, 0, 0 $largeArcflag, $endx $endy L $circendx $circendy\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\"  />";
```

[and generates a path like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7kVx.png)

now the rest of the path needs to complete it like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRJJL.png)

Hope this explains it better

EDIT 2:

I have an approach which is working alright but I have one problem.

```
    for ($i=0; $i<count($json_a->pie); $i++) {

      //value in degrees
      $valdeg = $json_a->pie[$i]->value1 / $valges * 360.0;
      //startang is 0 in the first iteration
      $endang = $startang + $valdeg;

      //transform deg in rad of start and end angle
      $valradstart = ($startang-90) * $M_PI /180.0;
      $valradend = ($endang-90)* $M_PI /180.0;

      if ($endang - $startang <= 180){
        $largeArcflag = 0;

      }else {
        $largeArcflag = 1;
      }

        $valradstart2 = $valradstart + ($M_PI/6);
        $valradend2 = $valradend - ($M_PI/6);

      //calculate the start and end coordinates
      $startx= $x + ($radius * cos($valradend));
      $starty= $y + ($radius * sin($valradend));
      $endx= $x +  ($radius * cos($valradstart));
      $endy= $y +  ($radius * sin($valradstart));

      //inner
      $innerstartx= $x + ($innerradius * cos($valradend));
      $innerstarty= $y + ($innerradius * sin($valradend));
      $innerendx= $x +  ($innerradius * cos($valradstart));
      $innerendy= $y +  ($innerradius * sin($valradstart));


      //height depending on var in .json
      //$circradius -= $pieheight;
      //circle around the middle for the fold up
      $circstartx= $x + ($circradius * cos($valradend));
      $circstarty= $y + ($circradius * sin($valradend));
      $circendx= $x +  ($circradius * cos($valradstart));
      $circendy= $y +  ($circradius * sin($valradstart));

      //circle around the middle for the fold up
      $circstartx2= $x + ($circradius * cos($valradend2));
      $circstarty2= $y + ($circradius * sin($valradend2));
      $circendx2= $x +  ($circradius * cos($valradstart2));
      $circendy2= $y +  ($circradius * sin($valradstart2));

      $startx2= $x + ($radius * cos($valradend2));
      $starty2= $y + ($radius * sin($valradend2));
      $endx2= $x +  ($radius * cos($valradstart2));
      $endy2= $y +  ($radius * sin($valradstart2));

      $innerstartx2= $x + ($innerradius * cos($valradend2));
      $innerstarty2= $y + ($innerradius * sin($valradend2));
      $innerendx2= $x +  ($innerradius * cos($valradstart2));
      $innerendy2= $y +  ($innerradius * sin($valradstart2));





      //write into the svg file
      $arcpath = "<path d=\"M $circstartx $circstarty L $startx $starty A $radius $radius, 0, 0 $largeArcflag, $endx $endy\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\"  />";
      //$arcpath = "<path d=\"M $startx $starty A $radius $radius, 0, 0 $largeArcflag, $endx $endy L $circendx $circendy\" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\"  />";
      $lineconnect = "<path d=\"M $circendx $circendy L $circstartx2 $circstarty2 M $circendx2 $circendy2 L $circstartx $circstarty \" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-dasharray=\"1, 1\"  />";
      $line2 = "<path d=\"M $circstartx2 $circstarty2 L $innerstartx2 $innerstarty2 M $innerendx2 $innerendy2 L $circendx2 $circendy2  \" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\"  />";
      $innerarcpath ="<path d=\"M $innerendx2 $innerendy2 A $innerradius $innerradius, 0, 0 $largeArcflag, $innerstartx2 $innerstarty2 \" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\"  />";
      $innerarcpath2 ="<path d=\"M $innerstartx $innerstarty A $innerradius $innerradius, 0, 0 $largeArcflag, $innerendx $innerendy \" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-dasharray=\"1, 1\"  />";
```

I now only need to access a point on the middle and inner circle with a given distance.

So e.g. a point that is on the arc but 10px along the line of the arc.

Is there any way that you can access a point like that?

```
$valradstart2 = $valradstart + ($M_PI/6);
        $valradend2 = $valradend - ($M_PI/6);
```

I tried it like this but the distance on the arc comes out different depending on the size of the pie chart.

I only need a way to access a point on an Arc X distance to the right and left.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you need the right-angle line to be a part of the path itself? Otherwise, you could define a [marker](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#Markers) that is a vertical line and let the browser/renderer do the tangent calculation for you.

Comment: You are probably going to need to use some trigonometry (sin() and cos() etc).  If you don't know how to do that, there are plenty of online resources to get you started.  If you want us to help you, you should at least show us what you have right now (ie add your code to the question)  .

Comment: Hey, use some basic geometry: the way along the arc is calculated by `s= radius * angle`. So, if you want to calculate the `angle` for a given arc-length `s` on a circle just use `angle = s/radius`. The result is to be interpreted as radian.

Answer (score 0):

As Paul LeBeau already commented, you will probably have to work with some `sin` and `cos` functions to get what you want. In particular, when it comes to arcs and curves, things get a bit more complicated.

However, there exists a simple solution, when you work with

- straight lines and
- use relative drawing commands in your path (small letter `l` for "line")

You will automatically draw at *right angles* if you follow an `l<a>,<b>` line by `l<n*b>,<-n*a>` or `l<-n*b>,<n*a>` (`n` can be an arbitrary factor). Check out the little fiddle below. By entering any values into the interactive prompt you will be generating lines at different angles, but always perpendicular to each other.

```js
var [a,b]=prompt('please enter a,b:','40,70').split(',');
document.querySelector('svg').innerHTML='<path d="M20,20 l'
           +(  2*a)+','+(  2*b)
       +' '+(-.5*b)+','+( .5*a)
       +' '+(-.5*a)+','+(-.5*b)
       +' '+     b +','+(   -a)
       +'" stroke="#000" fill="none" >';
```

```html
<svg width=400 height=400></svg>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! I tried it but unfortunately it doesnt seem to work, maybe I'm missing something obvious. 

My code looks like this: 
$circendxoff = $circendx * 0.06;
$circendyoff = $circendy * (-0.06);

$lineconnect = "<path d=\"M $endx $endy L $circendx $circendy l $circendxoff $circendyoff \" fill=\"none\" stroke=\"black\" stroke-dasharray=\"1, 1\"  />";

Answer (score 0):

#### Second answer, now addressing the OP's *modified* question:

If you want to draw a **pie chart** with some fixed gaps between the segments, you could do something like the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="600">
<g style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
<?php 
function pt($r,$ang,$mns=-1){ global $x,$y,$rad,$gap;
  $a=($ang-90)*$rad-$mns*asin($gap/$r); 
  return sprintf('%0.2f,%0.2f',$x+$r*cos($a),$y+$r*sin($a));
}
// define global variables:
$json_a=new stdClass();
$json_a->pie=array(30,20,40,40,30,30); // pie chart values: as few or many as you like!
$r=50;$x=210;$y=210;$ri=100; $rc=200;
$a360=360/array_sum($json_a->pie); $M_PI=3.14159265358; $rad=$M_PI/180.;
$out='';$gap=4;$ang1=0;      // start angle

foreach ($json_a->pie as $num) {

  $dang = $num * $a360;       // delta angle
  $laf  = $dang > 180? 1 : 0; // Large Arc Flag
  $ang2 = $ang1 + $dang;      // second angle

  $out.= '<path d="M'.pt($rc,$ang1).'L'.pt($r, $ang1)."A $r,$r, 0,$laf,1 "  .pt($r,$ang2,1).
                  'L'.pt($rc,$ang2,1)."A $rc,$rc, 0,$laf,0, ".pt($rc,$ang1).'" style="fill:hsl('.floor($ang1).',80%,55%)" />'."\n";
  $ang1=$ang2;
}
echo "$out";
?></g></svg>
```

A php-demo can be found under http://rextester.com/HGGAH45381.

This produces the following:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="800" height="600">
<g style="stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
<path d="M214.00,10.04L214.00,160.16A 50,50, 0,0,1 249.54,179.39L375.21,97.28A 200,200, 0,0,0, 214.00,10.04" style="fill:hsl(0,80%,55%)" />
<path d="M379.59,103.98L253.91,186.09A 50,50, 0,0,1 260.00,210.13L409.61,222.53A 200,200, 0,0,0, 379.59,103.98" style="fill:hsl(56,80%,55%)" />
<path d="M408.95,230.50L259.34,218.10A 50,50, 0,0,1 222.15,258.50L246.86,406.57A 200,200, 0,0,0, 408.95,230.50" style="fill:hsl(94,80%,55%)" />
<path d="M238.97,407.89L214.26,259.82A 50,50, 0,0,1 165.96,233.68L28.49,293.99A 200,200, 0,0,0, 238.97,407.89" style="fill:hsl(170,80%,55%)" />
<path d="M25.28,286.66L162.75,226.36A 50,50, 0,0,1 166.09,186.09L40.41,103.98A 200,200, 0,0,0, 25.28,286.66" style="fill:hsl(246,80%,55%)" />
<path d="M44.79,97.28L170.46,179.39A 50,50, 0,0,1 206.00,160.16L206.00,10.04A 200,200, 0,0,0, 44.79,97.28" style="fill:hsl(303,80%,55%)" />
</g></svg>
```

Notice the gap between the segments. This gap is now (=recently edited!) calculated by `$deltaAngle = asin($gap/$radius)`. The calculation is integrated in function `pt()`. The original calculation on the basis of the arc length (without using `asin()`) produces errors for largers gaps.

Comment: It's best to revert such changes to the question rather than have your answers chase it as it moves.